# git diff returns incorrect

Tags: git, branch, diff

I am trying to check my master branch against another branch. It is hosted on bitbucket and I have verified there that branch (called incremental) is just returning nothing. So when I diff the branch like this:

```
git diff master..incremental
```

I get nothing. In case it makes a difference I'm on the master branch as this ourput shows:

```
>LLG_db conryf$ git branch
  component_integration
  incremental
* master
```

Like I said, I'm sure the branches differ but none of those diff are showing up. Here is a bit of the bitbcket output (the branches are way different):
[image]

Comment: How do you know that the contents of the branches are different? They might've been different at some point but later converged, e.g. because you've updated _incremental_ from _master_ (`git merge master` from _incremental_) and then merged back to _master_ (`git merge incremental` from _master_).

Comment: What makes you sure that the two branches differ?

Comment: I can view the files on bitbucket and diff them there. I know of one specific file that is different. I'll attach the pic from bit bucket so you can see.

Comment: Did you perform $git fetch recently?

Comment: `git diff` doesn't go out and look at what's in BitBucket, it compares your local branches. If you haven't `fetch`ed (or `pull`ed, though `fetch` is better IMO) recently this might be the cause of your confusion.

Comment: And if you perform git-fetch, you'll need to compare against origin/incremental, or pull incremental first

Comment: Also, I would recommend getting out of the habit of using the `..` operator with `git diff` - it should be `git diff A B`, not `git diff A..B`. They don't mean the same thing in most `git` commands, with `A..B` specifying a range of commits instead of two specific commits. `git diff` currently has some hackery to interpret the range notation "as expected", but I think it helps to think of `git diff` as comparing two specific states...

Comment: I did `git pull` before this. Just ran `git fetch` for good measure. `git diff master incremental` still doesn't work. However `git diff master origin/incremental` does! @Robert if you make your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just be sure you're doing diff against updated ref:

```
$ git fetch
$ git diff master..origin/incremental
```

or

```
$ git checkout incremental
$ git pull
$ git diff master..HEAD
```